# On Mac, where does the Microsoft AutoUpdate save the downloaded files?

Tags: macos, microsoft-office

I have a macbook with Mac OS X El Captain Version 10.11.2.

After the Microsoft AutoUpdate finishes its job, one window will pop up, asking if you want to install all the updates. If you select yes, you will go through all the updates.

If you select cancel or no, the Microsoft AutoUpdate will scan your Office suite again, and ask you again if you want to download all the updates you seem to have just downloaded.

**Where does the Microsoft Office Suite Updates saves on the Mac?**

Attached pictures demonstrate the situation.

[image: Microsoft AutoUpdate]

Say, if I click cancel here, I would have to re-download all the updates again if I can't find where the downloads are.

Note: Why do I want to know this? It's because I accidentally hit cancel after the AutoUpdate finished its job, and I could not find the update download.

Comment: Even if you can the files the program does not support resume, so, it's not clear what having these files would get you

Comment: @Ramhound what if I have finished the downloaded ? I just accidentally hit the cancel button as shown above? I want to find out the downloaded file and continue the process.

Answer (score 2):

There are usually in folders named `MSau_xxxx` (xxxx is a 4 or 5 digit number) somewhere in `/private/var/folders/`

Go to the Terminal and execute this to find the exact location:

```
find /private/var/folders -name MSau_\*
```

Comment: In my case MS Updater was crashing and leaving a gigabyte of files in the folder, worse, according to console / activity monitor the failed update continued to run even after quitting causing a constant crash report and 23% CPU usage. Auto Update processes terminated in Terminal (permanently) - files removed.

Comment: sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper.plist  - process and Crash Reporter now cleared